# Customizing jquery selectList plugin to allow text box and remove?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, selectlist

I'm using this selectList plugin http://odyniec.net/projects/selectlist/

The problem is that for each element the user adds, I want allow them to specify a quantity.  I can do this with a template:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#mySelect').selectList({
      clickRemove: false,
     template: '<li><a>%text%<a/> - <input id="cnt_%value%" name="cnt%value%" type="text" value="1" /></li>'
      });
   });
```

I need to set clickRemove to false otherwise clicking on the text box remove the element.  However, with clickRemove: false, I can't figure out a way to allow the user to remove the element.

I've tried the suggestion from @Esailija, and this works to remove all of the items:

```
  $("ul.selectlist-list").on("click", "a", function () {
     var selectList = $('#mySelect').selectList({ instance: true });
     selectList.remove();
  });
```

And I can pass a hard-coded ID to remove() and that works, but I can't seem to find the value associated with the element I'm trying to remove. The value of the input element is a quantity, not the ID of the selected item.

So how to I get the value of the selected item to pass to remove?

<strike>I have tried to add a remove to the template:</strike>

```
  template: '<li><a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove()">%text%<a/> - <input id="cnt_%value%" name="cnt%value%" type="text" value="1" /></li>'
```

And that removes the item from the display, but does not allow it to be re-selected.  Is there a way to do this, or another plugin that would allow this type of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Without the inline handler)

```
$( "ul.selectlist-list" ).on( "click", "a", function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $input = $this.siblings("input"),
        selectList = $this.closest( ".selectlist-list" ).prev("select").selectList({instance: true});

    selectList.remove( $input.val() );
});
```

Even if it doesn't work (depends on your HTML structure), you get the idea. You need to call the `remove` method of a `.selectList` instead of just deleting elements directly as the plugin will have no idea that you did this.

http://odyniec.net/projects/selectlist/usage.html#api-methods

Answer (score 0):

Check source code of library, there is a solution for removing elements:

```
 $list.children().each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('value') == value || typeof value == 'undefined')
                remove($(this));
        });
```